# Assert Statements not functioning properly?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble understanding the nature of the assert statement

I thought that my program was not working properly, but when I made my main print out the return value that my program gave back to me, it was the exact value that my assert statement was supposed to accept. I'm not sure what is going on. I copy paste the function into another file, and copy paste my assert statements, this time different assert cases work(some of the cases that didn't work, now work, and some of the cases that worked, now don't).
When I worked through the debugger, it seemed that the assert statement is causing a certain logic statement

to not work at times, when the logic is supposed to. I don't understand why... Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Be careful when using [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert). First of all it's a macro which means it could evaluate its argument more than once. Secondly it does nothing when the `NDEBUG` macro is defined, which on some build-systems is set automatically for release builds. Thirdly, a failed assert will forcibly abort your program, making it look like a crash.

Comment: Yeah, will do! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you modify passed array inside of `removeDuplicatedValues` so first `assert((removeDuplicatedValues(duplicates1, 5)) == 1);` assertion succeeds but when you call next assertion using the same array `assert((removeDuplicatedValues(duplicates1, 4)) == 1);` it will fail because duplicates were already removed from that array. So you should rewrite your tests to use array only once (or even switch to dedicated unit test framework):

```
{
   string duplicates[7] = { "kek" , "hello" , "kek" , "daisy" , "bear" , "bear" , "bear" };
   assert((removeDuplicatedValues(duplicates, 5)) == 1); // ok
}
{
   string duplicates[7] = { "kek" , "hello" , "kek" , "daisy" , "bear" , "bear" , "bear" };
   assert((removeDuplicatedValues(duplicates, 4)) == 1); // ok
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know this. Thank you so much for being so concise and clear!